# skip/ignore/don't insert duplicate rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, insert, merge

Here's what I want:
Copy rows from tableA to tableB, but not any rows that are already in tableB. there is no PK or identiy, i simply want to check on each field, and don't insert if there's a matching row with all the same fields.  I've tried with both INSERT and MERGE:

```
 --try with INSERT
 INSERT TableB(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6, etc.)
 SELECT (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6, etc.)  
 FROM tableA as src
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableB as T
            WHERE               
            T.col1 = src.col1 AND
            T.col2 = src.col2 AND
            T.col3 = src.col3 AND
            T.col4 = src.col4 AND
            T.col5 = src.col5 AND
            T.col6 = src.col6, etc.)
```

I've also tried with MERGE:

```
  MERGE INTO tableA src
  USING tableB T
  ON (
            T.col1 = src.col1 AND
            T.col2 = src.col2 AND
            T.col3 = src.col3 AND
            T.col4 = src.col4 AND
            T.col5 = src.col5 AND
            T.col6 = src.col6, etc.)
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6, etc.)
  VALUES (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6, etc.);
```

Both do exactly the same thing: I'll do the insert (or merge), and initially all rows get imported, which is good, but then on second attempt (which should insert/merge 0 rows) it will insert/merge 60% of the rows.

I believe the issue is because I don't have a PK which is what i've seen on other posts here.  I just want to match on all fields though, is that possible?  Am i missing something?

Thanks for any advise/direction!

Comment: use cursor or recursive function this may help you

Comment: @AnantDabhi - a cursor is completely overkill for this

Comment: Thanks all!  I suspected NULL vs empty strings was causing the problem, hence the 60% of rows being effected.  The EXCEPT command offered by @hol worked great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use EXCEPT

```
INSERT INTO table1
SELECT * from table2
EXCEPT 
SELECT * from table1;
```

Have a look at the fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/34f0a/1)

Comment: beyond awesome!  I wasn't aware of the EXCEPT command.  Works like a charm!

Comment: Thanks. I am coming from Oracle where we use MINUS all the time, but I googled and found out that there is an equivalent for SQL Server called EXCEPT. So I thought I got to answer. To be sure I made a try on fiddle which is a good way to test SQL statements for database systems one is not familiar with.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` in your select statement to find records where all columns are `NULL`, like this:

```
 INSERT INTO tableB (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6, etc.)
 SELECT (A.col1, A.col2, A.col3, A.col4, A.col5, A.col6, etc.)  
 FROM tableA as A
 LEFT OUTER JOIN tableB AS B ON A.col1 = B.col1 AND A.col2 = B.col2 AND 
     A.col3 = B.col3 ... /* all the way to B.col99 or whatever */
 WHERE B.col1 IS NULL AND B.col2 IS NULL AND B.col3 IS NULL ... 
    /* all the way to B.col99 or whatever your last column is */
```

Comment: There might be a cleaner way using `MERGE`, but I'm rusty on that, and would have to look into that some more.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the problem is NULLs.  Try the query as:

```
INSERT TableB(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6, etc.)
SELECT (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6, etc.)  
FROM tableA as src
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableB as T
                  WHERE (T.col1 = src.col1 or t.col1 is null and src.col1 is null) AND
                        (T.col2 = src.col2 or t.col2 is null and src.col2 is null) AND
                        . . .
```

Comment: Thank you, I also suspected NULL was causing the issue.  The EXCEPT command by @hol takes that into account, and works great.

Comment: @russds . . . That solution is much simpler.  Glad to know it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may well have to do with NULL values.  The following script makes sure that if there are existing rows that have some columns NULL, they are matched.

```
--Create the sample source table.
--Notice that the columns allow NULL values...
CREATE TABLE #T1
(
  Col1 nvarchar(10) NULL,
  Col2 nvarchar(10) NULL,
  Col3 nvarchar(10) NULL
)

--Create the sample destination table.
CREATE TABLE #T2
(
  Col1 nvarchar(10) NULL,
  Col2 nvarchar(10) NULL,
  Col3 nvarchar(10) NULL
)
GO
--Populate the source table with some initial rows
--Notice that some column values are NULL
INSERT INTO #T1 (Col1,Col2,Col3) 
VALUES ('A','B',NULL),
        ('D','E','F'),    
        ('G',NULL,'I');
GO
--Verify the data in the tables 
--Table #T1 should have data in it
SELECT * FROM #T1;
--Table #T2 should be empty
SELECT * FROM #T2;
GO
--Copy the rows from #T1 to #T2
--where there are no matching rows.
INSERT INTO #T2(Col1,Col2,Col3)
SELECT 
  T1.Col1,T1.Col2,T1.Col3 
FROM #T1 AS T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN #T2 AS T2
ON  IsNull(T1.Col1,'') = IsNull(T2.Col1,'')
AND IsNull(T1.Col2,'') = IsNull(T2.Col2,'')
AND IsNull(T1.Col3,'') = IsNull(T2.Col3,'')
WHERE T2.Col1 IS NULL AND T2.Col2 IS NULL AND T2.Col3 IS NULL
GO
--Verify the data in the tables.  They should be the same now.
SELECT * FROM #T1;
SELECT * FROM #T2;
GO
--Add a some new rows to #T1
INSERT INTO #T1 (Col1,Col2,Col3) 
VALUES ('J','K','L'),
       ('M',NULL,'O'),
       ('P','Q','R'),
       ('A','B','C'); --THIS LAST ROW DOES NOT MATCH THE EXISTING A,B,NULL ROW AND WILL BE INSERTED ON MERGE
GO
--Merge the tables, and yes you could use MERGE where the ON clause handled NULLs
INSERT INTO #T2(Col1,Col2,Col3)
SELECT 
  T1.Col1,T1.Col2,T1.Col3 
FROM #T1 AS T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN #T2 AS T2
ON  IsNull(T1.Col1,'') = IsNull(T2.Col1,'')
AND IsNull(T1.Col2,'') = IsNull(T2.Col2,'')
AND IsNull(T1.Col3,'') = IsNull(T2.Col3,'')
WHERE T2.Col1 IS NULL AND T2.Col2 IS NULL AND T2.Col3 IS NULL
GO
--Verify the new data is in both tables.
SELECT * FROM #T1;
SELECT * FROM #T2;
GO
--Cleanup
DROP TABLE #T1;
DROP TABLE #T2;
```

Comment: Although your solution does address the issue of NULL in both columns not being treated as "equal", you introduce a new issue of an empty string being the same as NULL.